# Count based on row entries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

What I have:

- A table with distinct professor's name, quarter, and year values.
- A table with the professor's name, quarter, year, and a student's grade.

What I need to do is get the count of each type of grade (e.g. A, B, C) without regard to the + or - signs.

Does anyone know how I would accomplish this?

Comment: I have tried to use a cursor that fetches each name, quarter, and year tuple from the first table but I could not come up with a way to get the count of each grade without a group of subqueries within a while loop. It looks like Eggi's solution works however, but I will keep you all posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you did not say anything special regarding the output I will only output the grade and the how often it was found:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(grade, 1, 1), count(SUBSTRING(grade, 1, 1))
  FROM grades
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING(grade, 1, 1)
```

Comment: The substring function was exactly what I needed. Thank you!